# Set Operations on Character Data (string of integers)

Tags: r, character, set-operations

Does anyone know how to design a fast way to calculate the relative overlap of two columns? I would like to know how many elements of 'a' are in set 'b'. Ideally, a column 'c' is generated that stores these comparison values for each row. Really stuck on this one..

```
b <- c("20", "1, 8, 19, 20, 22, 23, 28, 34, 41", 
       "3, 8, 10, 11, 18, 20, 26, 37", 
       "1, 3, 6, 18, 21, 35", "NA", "1, 21, 33", "14, 37",
       "4, 14, 18, 23, 33, 37, 40", "14", 
       "4, 14, 20, 23, 33, 37, 40", 
       "2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 23, 25, 34, 40", 
       "6, 8, 10, 14, 19, 29, 33, 35, 36, 39, 41",
       "1, 20", "1, 28, 36", "14", 
       "1, 6, 33, 12, 39", "28", 
       "1, 6, 11, 13, 18, 19, 21, 28, 33, 35, 36, 39", 
       "35, 40", "20", "20, 38", "6, 8, 19, 22, 29, 32, 33, 34, 40",
       "1, 10, 21, 25, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40", "36")

a <- c("14", "10", "8, 39", "26, 39", "14, 20", "33, 36", "14", 
       "NA", "8, 39", "33, 36", "8, 39", "1, 36",  "10", "28, 33",
       "14, 20", "33, 40", "28, 34", "1, 36", 
       "8, 39",  "20", "14, 20", "29, 33", "36", "14")

df <- data.frame(a, b)

df$a <- as.character(df$a)
df$b <- as.character(df$b)
```

This function works well for row 18, but isn't easily scalable with sapply or equivalent.

```
length(intersect(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$a[18], ", "))),           
                 as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$b[18], ", "))))) /
length(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$b[18], ", "))))
# gives
[1] 0.1666667

length(intersect(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$a[5], ", "))), 
                 as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$b[5], ", "))))) / 
length(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$b[5], ", "))))
# gives
[1] 0
Warning messages:
1: In intersect(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$a[5], ", "))), as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$b[5],  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why a conversion with `as.numeric` is needed. That's the one giving you the warning. "NA" is considered a character value in your data frame, and that's a character value that can't be converted to numeric.

Note that a warning is not an error, so your code actually does work for line 5 as well (unless you expected NA).

I'd do the following:

```
getCounts <- function(x,y){
  x <- strsplit(x,", ")[[1]]
  y <- strsplit(y,", ")[[1]]
  mean(y %in% x)
}
# gives
> getCounts(df$a[5],df$b[5])
[1] 0
```

This is essentially what you did, but written up a bit more clear and using `mean(..%in%..)` instead of `length(intersect(..,..))/...`.

In order to do this over both vectors a and b, you can use `mapply`:

```
out <- mapply(getCounts,df$a, df$b)
```